# I want to particular path collection function work

Tags: xslt

I want to particular path collection function work.

Please check and correction my code.

**xml alias input:**

```
<folder_name>
<folder path="d:\123\2017_01_13"></folder>
<folder path="d:\123\\2017_02_14"></folder>
</folder_name>'
```

**xslt:**

```
<xsl:variable name="hhhh" select="'file:///d:/list_of_files.html'"/>
<xsl:result-document href="{$hhhh}">
    <xsl:text>&#xa;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:for-each select="document('file:///d:/xslt_path.xml')//@path">
        <xsl:variable name="aa" select="//@path"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="concat('file:///', $aa)"/>
        <xsl:variable name="ajeet_coll" select="collection(concat(ajeet_1, '/?select=*.xml;recurse=yes'))"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="$ajeet_coll">
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:for-each select="//image">
                <xsl:value-of select="@xlink:href"/>
                <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:result-document>
```

`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XSLT works with URIs, not with file paths. Thus, if you control the input, consider to use e.g. `<folder path="file:///d:/123/2017_01_13"></folder>`. Otherwise you have to convert the file paths to URIs first:

```
<xsl:variable name="ajeet_1" select="iri-to-uri(concat('file:///', replace($aa, '\\', '/')))"/>
```

You also need to change `<xsl:variable name="aa" select="//@path"/>` to simply `<xsl:variable name="aa" select="."/>` as inside the `for-each` you already process the attribute.